# Android studio fails to index R.xxx class with huge project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a 1M+ LOC with tons of XML files. The problem I usually get is that the R.xxx classes are usually unresolved after reopening Android Studio (currently I use AS 3.4, but this happened long before). The only solution I know is: close AS, remove `.idea` folder and then open AS again. This solution works but quite annoying since I lost my workspace information (like opened files history).

Comment: I'm curious, is your problem any relation with indexing limit of a file system? What kind of OS and file system that your Android Studio run on?

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Caches restart, this normally resolves any Resource errors I get?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I'm using Mac. AS is mostly using the default configuration. With a smaller project (~100k LOC), I have never got this problem.

Comment: @Shawn It works sometimes, but mostly work for wrong module index like Android standard library. I tried to remove only the `workspace.xml` or all but this file under `.idea` but this doesn't work.